# How to synchronize access to shared variable of multithreads in modular fashion using python?

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization

A python file contains two threads (sender thread, ack receiver thread). They synchronize the access to a shared variable "next_frame" using RLock. In my code, next_frame and lock are global.

```
import threading

#GLOBAL VARIABLES
next_frame = False
lock = threading.RLock()


class SenderThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, args, video_path):
        super(SenderThread, self).__init__()
        self.settings = vars(args)
        self.video_path = video_path

    def run(self):
        global next_frame
        global lock

        with lock:
           if next_frame:
              next_frame = False

class AckReceiverThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, args):
        super(AckReceiverThread, self).__init__()
        self.settings = vars(args)

    def run(self):
        global next_frame
        global lock

        while True:
        # receive ACK from serverside to send next frame
            ...
            with lock:
                if not next_frame:
                    next_frame = True
```

When I try to create & start these threads in a different python file, they don't run properly because of the global variables. 
Any design pattern, guide or example that help me to make it **modular component** (i.e. to be called anywhere)?

For the sake of modular development, I would really appreciate if you also provide some **design patterns in python** for multithreading, synchronization and global variables.